# Are there any resources for creating your own coin?

Tags: alternatives

I have some experiments I want to do for creating my own coin. I've seen stuff like coingen.io but I want to do it myself. I also will be messing with other things like the hashing algorithm. Are there any resources out there that gives a bit of guidance through this process? The best I've got so far is taking the dogecoin(or any other altcoin) first commit and comparing to the litecoin source. But this didn't produce very good results for me

Comment: Remember Dogecoin wasn't forked directly from Litecoin but rather was forked from Luckycoin - it might be clearer comparing the then-latest source trees of both.

Answer (score 2):

I recently heard of [www.coingen.io](http://coingen.io/) which enables to create your own crypto currency within minutes for minimum fee. (For minimum fee regarding the the you will be spending creating your own coin c. 50 USD)

I would like also to inform you that if you are seeing any investment/profit potential that we already have more than 100 so called [altcoins](http://coinmarketcap.com/) which are all almost the same with minumum differences.

If you are a bit programming skilled the complete guide is on [bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=225690.0) forum.

Commit this code on [GitHub](https://github.com/bfroemel/smallchange/commit/947a0fafd8d033f6f0960c4ff0748f76a3d58326)

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to smallchange which can be found here https://github.com/bfroemel/smallchange/commit/947a0fafd8d033f6f0960c4ff0748f76a3d58326

Comment: I was hoping there was an altcoin that had smaller commits, not the typical "here's one commit that births that altcoin, btw, it's huge"

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning for anyone who isn't aware that the Bitcoin client at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin is open source and available for download for those who wish to create their own cryptocurrency, subject of course to the conditions of the license.

Answer (score 0):

can use https://www.bitclone.net/ based on open-source Bitcoin and Litecoin code

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own digital coin with [www.bitclone.net](http://www.bitclone.net) platform. I have recently launched this project and currently looking for people to try it.

Comment: Are you affiliated with that site in any way? If so, it would be good to disclose that.

Comment: Do you have any experience with the service that you could share?

Answer (score -1):

Try [cryptonotestarter.org](https://cryptonotestarter.org/). If you are not familiar with CryptoNote platform, it allows for creation of completely anonymous cryptocurrencies (not Bitcoin forks). So far there are about 10 cryptocoins that were created with this technology. Bytecoin (BCN) was the first one launched in 2012 with a few forks spinning off within last two years. CryptoNoteStarter is a useful tool if you want to create your own CryptoNote-based coin. The interface is pretty simple, it looks like step-by-step guide that walks you through the stages of development.