# How to build my own bitcoin system?

Tags: altcoin-development

I want to know whether there exists any software that can let people create their own private personal Bitcoin, and mine their own Bitcoin.

Or any other software that can let people issue their own digital currency.

Comment: related: [Are there any resources for creating your own coin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/21428/5406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Bitcoin is open source, the source code *is* the software for creating new crypto coins.  Depending on what you want out of a new coin, and why you want it, the things you modify will be different.  However, the simple recipe is this:

1. Fork Bitcoin Core
2. Change the hard-coded genesis block in the source code
3. Change the port number that the protocol runs on
4. Recompile
5. Start mining, and convince others to join

There are other things you can change as well, such as hashing algorithm, block time, difficulty increase frequency, etc.  It all depends on your goal.

Comment: For the sake of someone searching for this, it's at the top of chainparams.cpp.  However, if you plan on creating your own blockchain and cryptocoin, you should probably be able to look it up yourself.  It's the easiest task ahead of you, so if you need my help on this one, you may want to rethink your entire goal.